# How to access attribute value in xml containing namespace using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-namespaces, elementtree

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<cim:Terminal rdf:ID="A_T1">
<cim:Terminal.ConductingEquipment rdf:resource="#A_EF2"/>
<cim:Terminal.ConnectivityNode rdf:resource="#A_CN1"/>
</cim:Terminal>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to get the Terminal.ConnnectivityNode element's attribute value  and Terminal element's attribute value also as output from the above xml. I have tried in below way!

**Python code:**

```
from elementtree import ElementTree as etree
tree= etree.parse(r'N:\myinternwork\files xml of bus systems\cimxmleg.xml')
cim= "{http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#}" 
rdf= "{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}"
```

Appending the below line to the code

```
print tree.find('{0}Terminal'.format(cim)).attrib
```

**output1:** : Is as expected

```
{'{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID': 'A_T1'}
```

If we Append with this below line to above code

```
print tree.find('{0}Terminal'.format(cim)).attrib['rdf:ID']
```

**output2**: key error in rdf:ID

If we append with this below line to above code

```
print tree.find('{0}Terminal/{0}Terminal.ConductivityEquipment'.format(cim))
```

**output3** None

How to get **output2** as A_T1 &  **Output3** as #A_CN1?

What is the significance of {0} in the above code, I have found that it must be used through net didn't get the significance of it?

Comment: Nitpick: `#A_T1` is not found in the XML document. There is only `A_T1`

Comment: sry thanks for the edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the `{0}` you're wondering about is part of the syntax for Python's built-in string formatting facility. [The Python documentation has a fairly comprehensive guide to the syntax.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings) In your case, it simply gets substituted by `cim`, which results in the string `{http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#}Terminal`.

The problem here is that `ElementTree` is a bit silly about namespaces. Instead of being able to simply supply the namespace prefix (like `cim:` or `rdf:`), you have to **supply it in XPath form**. This means that `rdf:id` becomes `{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID`, which is very clunky.

`ElementTree` does support [a way to use the namespace prefix for finding tags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces), but *not for attributes*. This means you'll have to expand `rdf:` to `{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}` yourself.

In your case, it could look as following (note also that `ID` is case-sensitive):

```
tree.find('{0}Terminal'.format(cim)).attrib['{0}ID'.format(rdf)]
```

Those substitutions expand to:

```
tree.find('{http://iec.ch/TC57/2008/CIM-schema-cim13#}Terminal').attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID']
```

With those hoops jumped through, it works (note that the ID is `A_T1` and not `#A_T1`, however). Of course, this is all really annoying to have to deal with, so you could also switch to [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.7.3) and have it mostly handled for you.

Your third case doesn't work simply because 1) it's named `Terminal.ConductingEquipment` and not `Terminal.ConductivityEquipment`, and 2) if you really want `A_CN1` and not `A_EF2`, that's the `ConnectivityNode` and not the `ConductingEquipment`. You can get `A_CN1` with `tree.find('{0}Terminal/{0}Terminal.ConnectivityNode'.format(cim)).attrib['{0}resource'.format(rdf)]`.

Comment: If the expected result for "output3" is `#A_CN1`, then the code for that should be `print tree.find('{0}Terminal/{0}Terminal.ConnectivityNode'.format(cim)).attrib['{0}resource'.format(rdf)]`.

Comment: @mzjn You're right - I didn't even catch the mismatch between selected element and desired attribute. Thanks. Updated!

Comment: thanks a lot obskyr! it  hepled me to move to next level!!