# Python attribute parsing returns None for xml:id

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, attributes, elementtree

I am trying to extract some information out of a tei file, using this code:

```
tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
body = root.find("{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}text/{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}body")  
for s in body.iter("{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}s"):
    for w in s.iter("{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}w"):
        wordpart = w.find("{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}seg")
        word = ''.join(wordpart.itertext())
        type = w.get('type')
        xml = w.get('xml:id') 
        print(type)             
        print(xml)
```

The output for `type` is correct, it prints e.g. "noun". But for `xml:id` I can only get `None`. This is an extract of the xml-file I need to parse:

```
<w type="noun" xml:id="w.4940"><seg type="orth">sloterheighe</seg>...
```

Comment: Why are there two quotation marks at the end of `xml:id="w.4940""`?

Comment: Small mistake, I edited it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of the `xml:id` attribute, you need to specify the namespace URI like this (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282975/how-to-access-attribute-value-in-xml-containing-namespace-using-elementtree-in-p) for more details):

```
xml = w.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id']
```

or

```
xml = w.get('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id')
```

Also, note that `type` is a built-in method in Python, so avoid using it as a variable name.